# How do I bust the cache so users get all the new static files (eg. style.CSS, main.js)?

Tags: javascript, caching, deployment, web-deployment, continuous-deployment

I'm deploying a whole new website redesign onto an existing domain. I will be manually replacing all files with the new files at 12:00AM, but how do I ensure users don't get a cached version of the old website (thereby breaking everything)?

Also, how do I change the sitemap so that the old one on google gets replaced?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to bust a cache.

The easiest way is to add an expiration header to files of that type. This can be done in an Apache configuration like so:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(gif|jpg|js|css)$">
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 10 years"
</FilesMatch>
```

You could also use a new query string value in the URL for each resource.

Another option is an updated version number within the filename that is routed to the update file.

You'll need to wait for Google's web crawler to index the changes. It's not something you'll have control over.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of ways , you can either use tools like webpack or plugins from gulp , grunt which will add a `hash` to the generated file name ,

So file name will be like this

```
someabc.RandomAlphanumeric.js
```

where `RandomAlphanumeric` randomly generated hash

If you are not using any build tool you can nema the file like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/folder/js/someFile.js?v1"></script>
```

Note the use of `?` .Usually  a time stamp is attached with the file name

Answer (score 0):

If you are redeploying an entire site I doubt you want to add ?v1 to every file.  And since your files are already cached I don't think that would be very effective anyway.  I would look at the server level for an option.  Most hosts have an option to disable or refresh your cache.  That is your best bet!